# Publish deploys dependencies on different machines

Tags: .net, .net-core

When ever I publish a .Net 2.1 Core application, via the Visual Studio (Version 15.8.7) to my web host, it uploaded all the dlls and pdbs that I change, as expected.

If I update any dependencies via a Nuget package update on my dev machine, and then publish again, I see it uploads those DLLs as well, as expected. I then commit my branch changes, which includes the .proj files and their updates (after Nuget Update)

However, when someone grabs the same repo, builds on their machine and then publishes, it seems to republish all the dependencies of .Net Core again (Even though I published the same branch before). For example:

```
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces.dll
```

It takes ages to upload (We have a very slow upload speed). Is there any reason that, even though we have the same repo, different machines seem to need to republish all .Net Core support files?

Once Machine A has published, subsequent publishes only publich the changed application files, unless Machine B does a publish.

Comment: Published via Visual Studio? Edit your question to include more details please.

Comment: Updated. Thanks,